# What exactly is main.py in python and how do I use it to create a one file executable using pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, function, tkinter, program-entry-point

I am currently working on a demo project while learning python and decided to use Tkinter as a user interface for my system. After finishing on the GUI and setting up a MySQL database I tried to use pyinstaller and py2exe to create a standalone .exe but it creates only one executable for one python file and I have 6 python files.

After research I found that most people with multiple python scripts have one main.py file that runs all their scripts and they use this to create a standalone .exe. So since this seems to be the solution but my question is, what is this main.py file and how do I write it so that when I create a .exe it runs my program and still has all the scripts working?

[all my python scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8ckw.jpg)

The first script that I want to execute when run my program is Login.py

Comment: Then why dont you create an exe with just `login.py`. That should automatically compile the other files too, not sure if this works if you use `--onefile` from pyinstaller, but pretty sure it works with `--onedir`.`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried using pyinstaller with --onedir but I still had the same issue. But after digging around some more I discovered auto-py-to-exe. It's has a user-friendly interface and can include other files and folders that are dependant on running your program. Here is the link https://medium.com/byte-sized-code/creating-windows-apps-using-python-f9db819e5f5